# How to inline h1 with p to match height?

Tags: css

How can i match the height of the h1 with the p tag? 
I want to set the h1 to the left followed by the p on the same base line

```css
.row_cont {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.row_cont h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.row_cont p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="page_container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row_cont">
        <h1>1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row_cont">
        <h1>2</h1>
        <p>Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row_cont">
        <h1>3</h1>
        <p>Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried vertical-align but it's not working, here is my [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/roybarak/qene77uf/)

Comment: `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">` really does not accomplish much besides cluttering up your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the sibling css selectors...

```css
h1, h1 + p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1><p>Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

this will only be possible by trial and error with the vaules, since the line (and the highest characters in a font) extends above the top of the digits you are using in H1. Basically, use `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: top` on both containers, then adjust the margin-top settings of both:

```
.h1_cont, .p_cont  {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.h1_cont h1 {
   margin-top: 0;
}
.p_cont p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/rk7nap5u/3/

Comment: thanks, i want the to match height - so the the p will start on the top of the h1

Comment: please note my changed answer

Comment: Oh, you wanted the same font-size in both? Well, then setting font-size and margins to the same settings for both (plus `display: inline-block`) is sufficient.